# Durandal Login Page display

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, durandal

I am using Durandal in HTML5  application. I want to show Login View first instead of Home Page on application loaded, how can I make the specific view to show.

```
 router.map([
                  { route: 'login', title: 'Login', moduleId: 'viewmodels/login', nav: true }
        ]).buildNavigationModel();

        log(app.title + 'Loaded!', null, true);
        return router.activate("login");
```

Thanks in Advance

ineffablep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Durandal 2.0 you would setup a default route by settting `route: ''` when defining the `route.map`.

e.g. the following would be defaulted to `login` and would have two items in that would show up in the navigation.

```
router.map([
    { route: '',  moduleId: 'viewmodels/login' ,
    { route: 'login', title='login', moduleId: 'viewmodels/login', nav: true },
    { route: 'home', title='home', moduleId: 'home/index', nav: true }
]).buildNavigationModel();

log(app.title + 'Loaded!', null, true);
return router.activate();
```

Note that `router.activate()` expects an optional options object in Durandal 2.0 that allows to set things like `root|hashChange|pushState|silent`. See http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Using-The-Router/ for the complete documentation.